# get product attribute on module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/image.phtml

Tags: magento-2.1, product-images, media-images

I have created a new product attribute of `media` type with code `img_hover`. 
Now I want to access it in the template file `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/image.phtml`

When I printing `$block->getData()`, I am not seeing the new attribute.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

In M2 they are getting the image using Builder.

> Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ImageBuilder

In the above class if you look `create` function in that only they are setting all the image related things.

```
public function create()
{
    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image $helper */
    $helper = $this->helperFactory->create()
        ->init($this->product, $this->imageId);

    $template = $helper->getFrame()
        ? 'Magento_Catalog::product/image.phtml'
        : 'Magento_Catalog::product/image_with_borders.phtml';

    $imagesize = $helper->getResizedImageInfo();

    $data = [
        'data' => [
            'template' => $template,
            'image_url' => $helper->getUrl(),
            'width' => $helper->getWidth(),
            'height' => $helper->getHeight(),
            'label' => $helper->getLabel(),
            'ratio' =>  $this->getRatio($helper),
            'custom_attributes' => $this->getCustomAttributes(),
            'resized_image_width' => !empty($imagesize[0]) ? $imagesize[0] : $helper->getWidth(),
            'resized_image_height' => !empty($imagesize[1]) ? $imagesize[1] : $helper->getHeight(),
        ],
    ];

    return $this->imageFactory->create($data);
}
```

So my suggestion is you have to use some plugin for this method and set you custom attribute image.